# In R, how can I access the first element of each level of a factor?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data frame like this:

```
n = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4) 
n <- as.factor(n)
s = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f") 
df = data.frame(n, s)  

df
  n s
1 2 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 3 d
5 4 e
6 4 f
```

and I want to access the first element of each level of my factor (and have in this example a vector containing `a, c, e`).

It is possible to reach the first element of one level, with

```
df$s[df$n == 2][1]
```

but it does not work for all levels:

```
df$s[df$n == levels(n)]
[1] a f
```

How would you do that?

And to go further, I’d like to modify my data frame to see which is the first element for each level at every occurrence. In my example, a new column should be:

```
  n s rep firstelement
1 2 a   a            a
2 2 b   c            a
3 3 c   e            c
4 3 d   a            c
5 4 e   c            e
6 4 f   e            e
```

Comment: +1 for posting a minimal, easily reproducible example, a clear description of the desired result, and the code you have tried, in your first SO question!

Comment: A small piece of advice for future questions: be careful so that your questions don't become moving targets. Me, sgibb and chit spent our time answering your _original_ question, i.e. the part _before_ the edit "And to go further".

Comment: Ok I understand! I thought that I had to edit the post as I asked. In these cases, should I create a new question or leave the update in the comments ?

Comment: I think it is difficult to give a general answer. Personally I think it is better to provide updates not only in the comments but also in the question. When a question becomes a 'moving target' is hard to say. In this case, my first answer solved your original question, but _not_ your edited part. On the other hand, the answer you accepted did not solve the original question, but was a very nice answer for your edit. I'm sure this is discussed much more thoroughly on Meta. See e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question). Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the function `ave` is useful in these cases:

```
df$firstelement = ave(df$s, df$n, FUN = function(x) x[1])
df
  n s firstelement
1 2 a            a
2 2 b            a
3 3 c            c
4 3 d            c
5 4 e            e
6 4 f            e
```

Answer (score 17):

**Edit**. The first part of my answer addresses the *original* question, i.e. *before* "And to go further" (which was added by OP in an edit).

Another possibility, using `duplicated`. From `?duplicated`: "`duplicated()` determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts."

Here we use `!`, the logical negation (NOT), to select *not* duplicated elements of 'n', i.e. first elements of each level of 'n'.

```
df[!duplicated(df$n), ]
#   n s
# 1 2 a
# 3 3 c
# 5 4 e
```

**Update** Didn't see your "And to go further" edit until now. My first suggestion would definitely be to use `ave`, as already proposed by @thelatemail and @sparrow. But just to dig around in the R toolbox and show you an alternative, here's a `dplyr` way:

Group the data by `n`, use the `mutate` function to create a new variable 'first', with the value 'first element of s' (`s[1]`),

```
library(dplyr)

df %.%
  group_by(n) %.%
  mutate(
    first = s[1])
#   n s first
# 1 2 a     a
# 2 2 b     a
# 3 3 c     c
# 4 3 d     c
# 5 4 e     e
# 6 4 f     e
```

Or go all in with `dplyr` convenience functions and use `first` instead of `[1]`:

```
df %.%
  group_by(n) %.%
  mutate(
    first = first(s))
```

A `dplyr` solution for your original question would be to use `summarise`:

```
df %.%
  group_by(n) %.%
  summarise(
    first = first(s))

#   n first
# 1 2     a
# 2 3     c
# 3 4     e
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is an approach using `match`:

```
 df$s[match(levels(n), df$n)]
```

*EDIT:* Maybe this looks a bit confusing ...

To get a column which lists the first elements you could use `match` twice (but with `x` and `table` arguments swapped):

```
 df$firstelement <- df$s[match(levels(n), df$n)[match(df$n, levels(n))]]
 df$firstelement
 # [1] a a c c e e
 # Levels: a b c d e f
```

Lets look at this in detail:

```
 ## this returns the first matching elements
 match(levels(n), df$n)
 # [1] 1 3 5

 ## when we swap the x and table argument in match we get the level index
 ## for each df$n (the duplicated indices are important)
 match(df$n, levels(n))
 # [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3

 ## results in
 c(1, 3, 5)[c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)]
 # [1] 1 1 3 3 5 5
 df$s[c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5)]
 # [1] a a c c e e
 # Levels: a b c d e f
```

Comment: Great! And how could I create a new column in my data frame which shows this first element for each level (in this example : a, a, c, c, e, e). Should I edit my post ?

Comment: @hhh: Sure it is possible. See my edit. Sorry that it looks so confusing.

Comment: For the second request, something like: `with(df, ave(s,n,FUN=function(x) x[1] ) )` might be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I prefer plyr package, it gives further freedom to manipulate the data.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(n),function(subdf){return(subdf[1,])})

  n s
1 2 a
2 3 c
3 4 e
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(firstelement = s[1]), by=n]
```

which would get you:

```
   n firstelement
1: 2            a
2: 3            c
3: 4            e
```

The `by=n` bit groups everything by each value of `n` so `s[1]` is getting the first element of each of those groups.

To get this as an extra column you could do:

```
dt[, newcol := s[1], by=n]
dt
#   n s newcol
#1: 2 a      a
#2: 2 b      a
#3: 3 c      c
#4: 3 d      c
#5: 4 e      e
#6: 4 f      e
```

So this just takes the value of `s` from the first row of each group and assigns it to a new column.

Comment: @eddi thanks for the edit and clean-up, but when I run this in R I still need the `as.character` to avoid the newcol ending up as numbers. I.e: `dt[, newcol:=as.character(s[1]), by=n]`

Comment: what version data.table are you using? perhaps you need an upgrade?

Comment: R 3.1.0 and data.table 1.9.2. So up to date. Must just be "one of those things".

Comment: Can you try data.table 1.9.3? Btw there is an issue with R 3.1.0 and data.table that I don't remember being fixed yet.

Comment: I'm guessing I'm seeing [this issue](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2014-April/002469.html)? I can't upgrade for the time being, but it does look like it's fixed in 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$s[sapply(levels(n), function(particular.level) { which(df$n == particular.level)[1]})]
```

I believe your problem is that you are comparing two vectors df$n is a vector and levels(n) is a vector.  vector == vector only happens to work for you since df$n is a multiple length of levels(n)

Answer (score 1):

Surprised not to see this classic in the answer stream yet.

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$n), function(x) x[1,]))
##   n s
## 2 2 a
## 3 3 c
## 4 4 e
```