# getting the first location where a person lived

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I would like to create a first place column where a person lived based on the year column. I have the data in the following format

```
year<- c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011)
person<- c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Brian', 'Brian','Vickey')
location<- c('London','Paris', 'Newyork','Paris','Paris','Miami')
df<- data.frame(year, person, location)
```

I would like to create a column called first place with values 0, 1. It is 1 if it is the first city else 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [In R, how can I access the first element of each level of a factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519297/in-r-how-can-i-access-the-first-element-of-each-level-of-a-factor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    mutate(FirstPlace = +(location[which.min(year)] == location))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   person [3]
#   year person location FirstPlace
#  <dbl> <fctr>   <fctr>      <int>
#1  2008   John   London          1
#2  2009   John    Paris          0
#3  2010   John  Newyork          0
#4  2009  Brian    Paris          1
#5  2010  Brian    Paris          1
#6  2011 Vickey    Miami          1
```

- `location[which.min(year)]` to find out the first place, then compare the first place with *location* column and convert the boolean result to integer.

If only look at the first year:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    mutate(FirstPlace = +(min(year) == year))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   person [3]
#   year person location FirstPlace
#  <dbl> <fctr>   <fctr>      <int>
#1  2008   John   London          1
#2  2009   John    Paris          0
#3  2010   John  Newyork          0
#4  2009  Brian    Paris          1
#5  2010  Brian    Paris          0
#6  2011 Vickey    Miami          1
```

Comment: It should be 1 for Brian for year 2009 and 0 for year 2010

Comment: just the first year of that person has to be 1 and 0 otherwise. please advise

Comment: @user3570187 OK. In that case you want to look at the year instead of location. You might do `+(year == min(year))` in `mutate`.

Answer (score 3):

with `data.table`you can do:

```
library("data.table")
year<- c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011)
person<- c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Brian', 'Brian','Vickey')
location<- c('London','Paris', 'Newyork','Paris','Paris','Miami')
df<- data.frame(year, person, location)
setDT(df)[, firstPlace:=as.integer(min(year)==year), person]
# > setDT(df)[, firstPlace:=as.integer(min(year)==year), person]
# > df
#    year person location firstPlace
# 1: 2008   John   London          1
# 2: 2009   John    Paris          0
# 3: 2010   John  Newyork          0
# 4: 2009  Brian    Paris          1
# 5: 2010  Brian    Paris          0
# 6: 2011 Vickey    Miami          1
```

or (as @Frank mentioned) if your data is sorted by person and year

```
setDT(df)[, firstPlace:=+!duplicated(person)]
```

or (a variant of this)

```
setDT(df)[, firstPlace:=+(rowidv(person)==1)]
```

Comment: I would like to create a column called first place with value 1 if it is the first city and 0 otherwise, please suggest changes

Comment: @user3570187 You can edit your question to make it transparent what output you want. Fwiw, if your data is sorted by person and year, `+!duplicated(df$person)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
first_city<-df%>%
group_by(person)%>%
  arrange(year)%>%
  slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
first_city <- df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  top_n(1, year)
```

Or as a extra column in your data:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(first_city = head(location, 1))
```

Indicating the first city with a `1` and `0` otherwuse (only for the first year)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(first_city = as.integer(head(location, 1) == location & year == min(year))) 

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   person [3]
#    year person location first_city
#   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>         <int>
# 1  2008 John   London            1
# 2  2009 John   Paris             0
# 3  2009 Brian  Paris             1
# 4  2010 John   Newyork           0
# 5  2010 Brian  Paris             0
# 6  2011 Vickey Miami             1
```

Comment: Can you explain how `head` gets turned into a number with  `as.integer(head(location, 1))`, and what it indicates?

Comment: The boolean expression `head(location, 1) == location & year == min(year)` is `TRUE` if the location is the first location of that person and if the year is also the minimum year, otherwise it's `FALSE`. This boolean vector is then turned into a number with `as.integer`, setting `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0. You could just leave out the `as.integer` and see the boolean version.

Comment: Thanks Kath!! Your answer seems to work well with `...mutate(first_city = +(head(location, 1) == location ))`